# api documentation for java web application?

Tags: java

after i created a java web application in netbeans i encounter class like

javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.

I cant find this class in the usual SE API documentation online.

is there another API documentation for web application classes in java?

Comment: Pointer for future cases: every time you see package name that starts with `javax`, you can be at least 90% sure it's not in JavaSE.

Comment: That's not true at all.  There is Swing, Security, XML, Multimedia, Cryptography, Management and many others in the SE API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out the java EE javadoc here: http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/

To elaborate, HttpServletRequest and other similar classes are part of the Java Enterprise Edition platform, so you will not find them documented in the Standard Edition (SE) Javadoc API.

Comment: but where is the EE 6 API javadoc?

Comment: See the servlet-api.jar, included with e.g. Tomcat

Answer (score 2):

See the [Java EE 6 SDK and Java EE 6 Web Profile SDK Docs & Resources](http://java.sun.com/javaee/sdk/resources.jsp) page and, more specifically:

> #### Developer Resources
>
> - [Java EE 6 Samples](http://java.sun.com/javaee/reference/code/)
> - [Java EE 6 Technologies](http://java.sun.com/javaee/technologies/)
> - [API Documentation](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/)
> - The Java EE 6 Tutorial, Volume 1: Basic Concepts - [HTML](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/)
> - The Java EE 6 Tutorial: Basic Concepts and Advanced Topics (login or registration required) - [PDF](https://www.sun.com/offers/details/java_ee6_tutorial.xml)
> - [Your First Cup: An Introduction to the Java EE Platform](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/firstcup/doc/)

The third link is what you're looking for.

PS: No offense but I think that you should spend some time browsing the Sun website and learn to find information by yourself. It's not that hard to find things there and it's offering very interesting resources.